# What is given priority in below scenario @Bean or @Component?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I am learning concepts of Spring & I came across @Bean & @Component annotations. I want to know what will happen in below scenario:

```
@Configuration
class ConfigClass {

  @Bean
  public ComponentClass ComponentClass() {
    return new ComponentClass(someDependency1, someDependency2, someDependency3);
  }
}

@Component
class ComponentClass{
  private SomeDependency1 sd1;
  private SomeDependency2 sd2;
  private SomeDependency3 sd3;

  public ComponentClass(SomeDependency1 sd1, SomeDependency2 sd2, SomeDependency3 sd3) {
    /* initialize here */
  }
}
```

I have declared *ComponentClass* as @Component which means it is a spring bean now. But I have also defined a @Bean for it in config class separately.

1. Which of these beans will be actually used as by default Spring is singleton?
2. What happens when I remove @Component?

Comment: I recommend you to try your hands on Spring. To check such a scenario yourself, you will need only 1 file and 90% of code you already have written in the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring will notice a mistake and throw `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` during application startup.
If you remove `@Component` annotation it will work as expected, `@Bean` will be used for initialization.

Comment: I tried to look for any official documentation for this or some reference, but could not find. Can you provide some link if possible?

Comment: [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.html) and here is a good [article](https://springframework.guru/fixing-nonuniquebeandefinitionexception-exceptions/)